# Trying to have a simple node server point all routes at index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js

Total node newbie but would like to point all my backbone deeplinked routes at index.html so I've added this script to server.js in the route of my project, but none of the deeplinked routes seem to register my terminal and the pages consequently fail. Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

**JS - server.js**

```
var express = require('express');

var server = express();
server.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// I've also tried /*
server.get('*', function(req, res){
    console.log('serve', req, res, __dirname);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

var port = 8000;
server.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: is index.html in the root?

Comment: yeah it's right in there beside server.js

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make sure that all http methods serve the index.html, you need to use *all* instead of *get*.

```
server.all('*', function(req, res){
    console.log('serve', req, res, __dirname);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Furthermore, make sure that you're starting the node server from within the directory where the index.html is located.